# Groovy pattern maching issue

Tags: java, groovy

in one of my groovy class i am trying with the pattern matching but no success.

```
def TestMap = ['/test.domain.local/ig':'serverx']

nodeName = 'test.domain.local'


for (kv in TestMap){
   if(nodeName != null && ("${nodeName}" =~ "${kv.key}")) {
      println "${kv.value}";
   }
}
```

but somehow if condition is not being true and I don't understand why? please note that this is not complete codes. main focus here is on pattern matching.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The if condition should be reversed (the matching is done in the wrong way)

```
def TestMap = [/test.domain.local/ig:'serverx']

nodeName = 'test.domain.local'

for (kv in TestMap){
    if(nodeName != null && ( "${nodeName}" =~ "${kv.key}")){
        println "${kv.value}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i was looking at http://mrhaki.blogspot.ch/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html and in shown examples it is like:

assert 'Groovy rocks!' =~ /Groovy/  // =~ in conditional context returns boolean.

so in my case 'nodename' =~ Pattern

and according to you it is Pattern =~ 'nodename'

and it works too.

Could you please share more details?

Comment: It always works this way `<what you need to test> =~ <pattern that should be matched (regex)>` e.g. `"lol" =~ /lol/`.

Comment: Then "${nodeName}" =~ ${kv.key}" should be the correct one.
          'test.domain.local' =~ /test.domain.local/ig

isnt it? in your first response you said i need to reverse

           "${kv.key}" =~ "${nodeName}"
            /test.domain.local/ig =~ 'test.domain.local'

and this appears to work for some reason.

Comment: Yes, I see it, you need to remove `'` from map key. Should be `[/test.domain.local/:'serverx']`. It wasn't regex.

Comment: accepted and also corrected your original answer to reflect your last response. thanks for the help.